# How to sort a database in netbeans

Tags: java, sql

I'm trying to build a application where i need to sort the table data in the ascending order using employee no,year and month.This is the code i wrote but the table is not sorting.Can someone tell me the proper way to do it?

try{

```
    String sql="Select * from Allowance order by Employee_No,Year,Month ASC";
    pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    rs=pst.executeQuery();
```

Comment: this is not related to Netbeans, but with java or other language. also you are sorting a result set from a search from a table not the whole databse. Lack of minimal knowleadge

Comment: The statement is correct, you should give us an example of how it is "not working"

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working. You get a sorted ResultSet but you're not sorting the database itself.
And I think sorting the database isn't neccessary, because you can always get sorted data easy with that code.